# moment generating function of gambling

Tags: calculus, probability, generating-functions

Suppose a gambler starts with one dollar and plays a game in which he or she wins one dollar with probability $p$ and loses one dollar with probability $1-p$. Let $f_n$ be the probability that he or she first becomes broke at time $n$
for $n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$ Find a generating function for these probabilities?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, the way this will work is to consider the ways how the gambler goes broke for an arbitrary $n$.  This gambler must lose one more than he wins, and the last play results in a loss.  Thus, $n$ must be odd for the probability to be nonzero, e.g., $n=2 k+1$.  Further, the other $2 k$ plays are evenly distributed in wins and losses, so it is just a matter of figuring out how many combinations of wins and losses there are for a given $k$.  This number is $(2 k)!/(k!)^2$, and the probability $f_{2 k+1}$ is

$$f_{2 k+1} = \frac{(2 k)!}{(k!)^2} p^k (1-p)^{k+1} = \binom{2 k}{k} p^k (1-p)^{k+1}$$

The generating function you want is

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f_{2 k+1} \, x^{2 k+1} = (1-p) x\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2 k}{k} [p(1-p) x^2]^k$$

It turns out that the series on the right is the Taylor series of a well-known function.  This is your generating function:

$$f(x) = \frac{(1-p) x}{\sqrt{1-4 p (1-p) x^2}}$$

Comment: awesome! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome.  If you found the answer useful, please accept it by clicking on the check mark to the left.